# Add a letter to make this true

Tags: lateral-thinking, rebus

Add a letter to make this true.

[image]

> Please retain the `=` sign. (I consider solutions involving ≠, for example, to be trivial)

Comment: equal by definition, as in, you are declaring that 148 is seven by definition which is an inherently true statement. (or a statement with no truth value depending on the propositional calculus model you are using)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> 1 B 4 8 = 7

Because :

> one before eight is seven (8-1 = 7)

Comment: Nice one - you have it.

Comment: A rebus as a solution instead of the puzzle. I like it.

Comment: Ah I was thinking _1 from 8 = 7_. I was trying to decide whether that should count, since you're exchanging a letter instead of actually adding one.

Answer (score 18):

> 148 = 7F

also

> <strike>148 = 78</strike>
>  above is with digit, so replacing it with
>  148 = 7J

also

> 148 = 7D

because

> In various radix systems:
>  ${148}_{(10)}=7F_{(19)}$
>  ${148}_{(10)}=78_{(20)}$
>  ${148}_{(11)}=7J_{(22)}$
>  ${148}_{(9)}=7D_{(16)}$

Comment: The 2nd one doesn't work because 8 isn't a letter. Are radix systems just different bases?

Comment: @QuestionAsker Yes.

Comment: @QuestionAsker Yes, they are indicated in subscript in the explanation. There are other examples too. With letters only ;)

Answer (score 6):

Add

> An italicized I over the top of the = turning it into ≠ or the not equals sign.

Comment: For any questions in this format, like match stick/add a line problems, I would consider these solutions to be trivial. Please retain the `=` sign.

Comment: A lot of times the trivial solution is the one that the asker is looking for though, they are banking on the people overlooking the obvious (and trivial to one person is clever to another). I am not sure there is a good way to tag things to indicate what type of problem it is without giving away the solution... I think the only way is to make the problem more precise. if messing with = is not on the table, add it to the question.

Comment: Of course - no problem.

Comment: Maybe a no overylays statement when the word "add" is used since i have seen it used both ways in puzzles.. (add in between and add on top) for future puzzles of this form...

Comment: Actually, I think I can allow both, as there aren't any other solutions (at least I don't think), unless you try to cross the whole thing out or change the `=` sign.

Answer (score 4):

Add "m" to for ("4," get it?). 1 from 8 = 7

Comment: You should use spoilers.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very boring answer:

> but 148a = 7 or any variation adding a letter variable, while being a trivial addition--it does invoke a rather great meaning that is fundamental to algebra.

I think you were looking for a read aloud style puzzle

> one for eight is seven
>  one "B" for eight is seven

Comment: That's the first thing my friend said when I asked him, actually — "$148 = 7x$ where $x={148\over7}$" :)

Comment: Although you may find your answer boring, you should use Spoilers.